# Explain Quora's "Ask to Answer" feature

Tags: quora

Could someone please explain the "Ask to Answer" feature on Quora?

Comment: [This](http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/14/quora-gamifies-credits-and-ask-to-answer-suggestions-live-for-everyone/) TechCrunch article explains it.

Comment: @Alex: I must be a bit thick, but I still don't get it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, when you ask a question, (1) Quora suggests a set of users determined algorithmically to better answer your question — *that are not among your friends* (this is important!) —, and (2) the suggested users have an "answering fee" that they (can?) require in order to answer the respective question.

For the first part:

> The first is **suggestions for Ask to Answer, a list of people on Quora who can best answer a particular question**. We've always offered the ability to ask someone to answer a question, but you had to know about that person ahead of time. Our new suggestions list *identifies people who have written good answers to similar questions, so you can discover and ask people you might not otherwise have found*.

For the second part:

> The second part is **credits, a virtual currency that's used to ask people to answer**. Everyone on Quora will get a balance of credits, and *each person on the new suggestions list has an ask to answer price*.

From [this Quora](http://www.quora.com/Joel-Lewenstein/Joels-Posts/New-on-Quora-Suggestions-for-Ask-to-Answer-and-Credits) thread.

Comment: Update 2016: [Quora has killed the credit feature](http://qr.ae/RUWz3l)